# How to remove mousedown event using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am using Highcharts library.I have a div with class container and that div having 5 events including mousedown but i don't need mousedown event for that particular container class

```js
 $('.container').off('mousedown'); or $('.container').unbind('mousedown');
```

```js
setDOMEvents:function(){
var b=this,c=b.chart.container;
c.onmousedown=function(a)
{
b.onContainerMouseDown(a)
};
c.onmousemove=function(a){
b.onContainerMouseMove(a)
}}
```

I tried unbind() and off() but it won't work.
I am using JQuery version 1.3

I need a solution for remove or disable that event

Comment: Please show the code you've tried.

Comment: I have a div with class container and that div having 5 events including mousedown but i don't need mousedown event for that particular container class $('.container').off('mousedown'); or $('.container').unbind('mousedown');

Comment: Umm ... we'd like to see how you're attaching the event. Please edit your question to include the code, don't post code in the comments.

Comment: Would you kindly show how the `onmouse` event was created and help us understand the context/scope, please? This will help us identify a possible solution for you.

Comment: @DamienWilson that all are default events of highchats library

Comment: Your questions would be 1000 times better if you make that none-working snippet into a working snippet that demonstrates the issue.   The snippet editor even makes adding jQuery very simple.  It doesn't have to be the exact code your currently editing, as long as it demonstrates the problem.

Comment: .off() will only work if you used .on() to attach the event. Are you able to be more specific with your code example... i.e. show how you're attaching the event? Many thanks.

Comment: Ok, have you tried removing the event using Highcharts API? You could try `removeEvent()` https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.removeEvent%3CT%3E